# Postgresql: STRING_AGG() optimal way to order by an undisplayed value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to generate a string of names in the order they logged in. I have working code but its ugly enough that I am sure I am missing a more direct method.

Goal, return a string of DISTINCT usernames in the order they last logged in.

1. I start with a list of names and dates.
2. I select the most recent row for each name. () t
3. I order that by date. () s
4. I STRING_AGG that giving me the string I want.

PgSql 9.6

Can I eliminate any of these nested queries?

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(s.name, ', ') AS names
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        t.name 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.name)
             t2.name
            ,t1.created
        FROM
            logins t1
        LEFT JOIN
            users t2 ON t2.id = t1.user_id
        ORDER BY t2.name, t1.created DESC
        ) t
    ORDER BY t.created DESC
    ) s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having you tried this?

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(s.name, ', ' ORDER BY created DESC) AS names
FROM (SELECT u.name, MAX(l.created) as created 
      FROM logins l JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id = l.user_id
      GROUP BY u.name
     ) ul;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` doesn't seem necessary.  User ids in `logins` should be valid.  If not, use the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had tried similar ORDER BY but always ran into aggregate errors.